# Downvotes with explanations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

It would be nice if we have some reason oriented down votes.is it possible to get something similar when we close/flag questions, because there are so many new user putting there question & they do get answers but down votes also,  this is going to decrease our site value as well. right now most of the user's who down vote they don't give a reason that makes me/new user to think twice that whats wrong with the question. everyone comes here to get solution not down votes...

Answer (score 4):

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/157384  There is already an "encouraging prod" pop-up for users with <2k rep.  Your rep is sufficiently high so you do not see this warning any more.  While not *exactly* like the close/flag dialog, it's fairly similar.

> there are so many new user putting there question & they do get answers but down votes also,this is going to decrease our site value as well.

I wholeheartedly disagree.  Downvotes show that a question is not a good question.  Having a site chock full of bad questions that are ranked similar to good questions will damage the site's reputation/value.

In a weird way, votes are not for the question askers they are for the rest of the community.  A down-voted question can still get answered.  It takes many downvotes to keep it truly "off the radar", and such a low score would clearly indicate that the question has deep problems that may prevent it from being answerable.  There is even a [sympathy upvote issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38595/sympathy-upvote-problem-on-questions) so the odds of actually netting negative rep from a bad question are fairly slim.

> everyone comes here to get solution not down votes

I do agree with the sentiment, but there is a certain contract between people who ask questions and people who answer questions.  A low quality question does not *deserve* high-quality answers.  If someone comes here for a solution, they should put as much effort into their question as others will put into their answers.

New users are greeted with a banner that encourages them to read the FAQ.  Additionally, the Ask a Question page has a short dynamic "How to Ask" guide along the right side of the form.  If a user gets past the FAQ, and gets past the "How to Ask" guide, and still asks a poor quality question - they *deserve* downvotes.

Bad questions do not happen by accident, they happen by ignorance.  For what it's worth, the GD community is *far* friendlier than the SO & MSO communities - and those are the bedrock on which the rest of the SE network is founded.  New users here are typically encouraged to read the FAQ and edit their questions, as opposed to being ridiculed or in anyway intentionally deterred.

Comment: I'm always surprised how sparing people are with downvotes, particularly with poor answers.

Comment: @e100 It's unfortunate when constructive honesty takes a backseat to feelings.  Too many users forsake potential improvements over the long-term in favor of "being nice" in the short-term.

Comment: @Farray --"A low quality question does not deserve high-quality answers. If someone comes here for a solution, they should put as much effort into their question as others will put into their answers." EXCELLENTLY WORDED.